# Is there a way to write an event handler in JavaScript without adding it to the tag or using addEvent?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to add an event listener to an element only by it's ID in JavaScript without using `addEventListener` or `click="eventHandler()"`? I vaguely remember a way to do it using the id of the element.

For example, here are two ways to add an event listener for a button that I'm not interested in:

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" onclick="doSomething()" />
```

Here is another:

```
myButton.attatchEvent("click", doSomething());
```

I'm not interested in the above two methods at this time. What I'm looking for is something like:

```
function myButton_clickHandler(event) {
   alert("hello world");
}
```

In the code above the browser knows that the event is for "myButton".

The reason I'm trying to figure this out is for research. I remember doing something like this in IE.

---

**UPDATE**

---

I did some more research and I found out that it may be a Microsoft only type of feature set referred to throughout their documentation by the names of, "**implicit event handler**", "**signature based handlers**" and "**AutoEventWireup**". These examples are for ASP.NET.

---

**First example:**

To create a handler for page events

1. In the code editor, create a method with the name Page_event.
2. For example, to create a handler for the page's Load event, create a method named `Page_Load`.

Note:
Page event handlers are not required to take parameters the way that other controls event handlers are.

ASP.NET pages automatically bind page events to methods that have the name Page_event. This automatic binding is configured by the `AutoEventWireup` attribute in the @ Page directive, which is set to true by default. If you set `AutoEventWireup` to false, the page does not automatically search for methods that use the Page_event naming convention.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Page.IsPostBack Then
        Response.Write("<br>Page has been posted back.")
    End If 
End Sub
```

---

**Second example:**

To add an event handler implicitly in Visual Basic

1. In the code editor, create an event-handling method with the appropriate signature. The method can be named anything you like.
2. Use the Handles keyword, specifying the control and event to which the method should bind.

The following code example shows an event handler for the Click event of a button named SampleButton. The method in the example is named Clicked.

```
Protected Sub SampleButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles SampleButton.Click
    ' Code goes here. 
End Sub
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: I've never heard of this for IE, where the function name alone allows for this, though you can assign a function to a property which will be called. Anyway, is this just research on methods available or a research website (probably the former, but just checking)?

Comment: I agree with @Qantas94Heavy - I've never heard of anything like this. Sure you're not thinking of AS3?

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't exist. `attatchEvent`, perhaps? Or just `myButton.onclick = function(event) { ... }`?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. But I remember thinking it was odd that I didn't have to add an event listener. I'm not thinking of AS3. It was back in Internet Explorer 4 days.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow - I updated the code examples with the correct method names.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - I'm trying to see if it's a supported way of adding event listeners for my own research purposes. I'm working on an HTML website creating project.

Comment: Maybe ask the button nicely to look around and discover what to do and when to do it on its own?

Comment: There's no native way to do this that I know of, but it is possible with a bit of extra code. Would you like me to write that up for you?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville - If you would be so kind.

Comment: I'm going to keep this question open for a while to see if some of the old timers remember anything like this. Hopefully we'll get it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment, I've written up the below code. For each function with an underscore present, the function finds the DOM element whose ID matches the section of the function name before the underscore, and gives the function to it as an `onclick` handler.

```
(function() {
    var e, prop;
    for(prop in window) {
        if(prop.indexOf("_") < 0 || typeof window[prop] !== "function") continue;
        e = document.getElementById(prop.split("_")[0]);
        if(typeof e !== "undefined") {
            e.onclick = window[prop];
        }
    }
})();
```

Paste the above code in, and you'll be able to do what you described in your question, i.e. attach an event like this:

```
function myButton_clickHandler(event) {
    alert("hello world");
}
```

Where `myButton` is the ID of your button. This will only work properly if the ID is unique.

Comment: This could probably be improved... Would you mind if I posted an answer to expand on this?

Comment: Not particularly. I'd like to see what you can come up with. I haven't finished refining it either.

Comment: Nice work fellas. These would do what I want without the browser support I thought might have existed.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Elliot's code, here's a suggestion:

```
(function() {
    var prop, match, elem;
    for(prop in window) {
        if( typeof window[prop] !== "function") continue;
        if( match = prop.match(/^(.*)_([a-z]*)Handler$/)) {
            if( e = document.getElementById(match[1])) {
                if( "on"+match[2] in e) {
                    e["on"+match[2]] = window[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

With this code, you can have `function myButton_clickHandler` as in Elliot's answer, but you can also attach other events, such as `myButton_focusHandler` for `onfocus`, or `someInput_changeHandler`. More importantly, it won't interfere with any functions you might have that happen to have an underscore in them. It will *only* look for functions with names that contain an underscore and have `Handler` at the end of the name... and even then only if the event type is supported.